# How to open Asp.Net project in another computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I prepared a project with Asp.net MVC at work with my work pc. But i have to open it on my own computer. I'm trying to run it but It doesn't work and i get a lot of errors. How can i open and run this project? Can you help me please :( It is shown in the picture

[image]

**EDIT**: I found out that it is because my home computer doesn't have the same version of .net sdk as my work computer. I resolved it.

Comment: For those of us unable to see your picture, it might help if you told us what the errors are.

Comment: @Minel, it sounds like you're missing a bunch of packages.  From Package Manager Console try to run `dotnet restore`

Comment: Everywhere is redlined. For example, Controller. ActionResult,View,every code :(

Comment: I tried dotnet restore from package manager console but it said: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Comment: It seems to be some package errors. Haven't you downloaded some NuGet packages at work, or there may be default packages installed? You may have to check and download them again, and be careful to set up correct versions. Hope this helps.

Comment: What Does Visual Studio say about errors? I mean have you tried to look in "quick actions", the yellow bulb, for more error description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `System.Linq` is red lined tells me your home computer doesn't have the same version of .net sdk as your work computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try install MVC 4 from custom packages on Visual Studio installer

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the same mvc installed on your computer